# What is a regex expression that can prune down repeating identical characters down to a maximum of two repeats?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, data-preprocessing

I feel I am having the most difficulty explaining this well enough for a search engine to pick up on what I'm looking for.  The behavior is essentially this:

```
string = "aaaaaaaaare yooooooooou okkkkkk"
```

would become `"aare yoou okk"`, with the maximum number of repeats for any given character is two.

Matching the excess duplicates, and then re.sub -ing it seems to me the approach to take, but I can't figure out the regex statement I need.

The only attempt I feel is even worth posting is this - `(\w)\1{3,0}`

Which matched only the first instance of a character repeating more than three times - so only one match, and the whole block of repeated characters, not just the ones exceeding the max of 2. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regexp should be `(\w)\1{2,}` to match a character followed by at least 2 repetitions. That's 3 or more when you include the initial character.

The replacement is then `\1\1` to replace with just two repetitions.

```
string = "aaaaaaaaare yooooooooou okkkkkk"
new_string = re.sub(r'(\w)\1{2,}', r'\1\1', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write

```
string = "aaaaaaaaare yooooooooou okkkkkk"
```

```
rgx = (\w)\1*(?=\1\1)
```

```
re.sub(rgx, '', string)
  #=> "aare yoou okk"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FqTHIH/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(\w)     # match one word character and save it to capture group 1
\1*      # match the content of capture group 1 zero or more times
(?=      # begin a positive lookahead
  \1\1   # match the content of capture group 1 twice
)        # end the positive lookahead
```